# How to mimic tableview movement with CAMediaTimingFunction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, core-animation

I have a tableview and another view, and I'd like to animate the other view so that it slows down and stops at the same time and animation curve as the tableview does when scrolled. So, I figure that I can implement

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

and use the `velocity` (pixels per millisecond), `targetContentOffset`, and the tableview's `decelerationRate` property to calculate how long it'll take to stop using the physics equation `d= (vi+vf) / 2  * t` to calculate the duration of my animation. **Once I have this, I just need the animation to decelerate at the same rate as the tableView, so that they look 'synced'. How would I do this using a `CAMediaTimingFunction` and the tableview's `decelerationRate` property?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `UIAnimation` and set the animation curve to `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut` using

`+ (void)setAnimationCurve:(UIViewAnimationCurve)curve`.

Calculate the animation duration using `time = velocity / acceleration`.

An alternative approach would be to use `[UIScrollViewDelegate scrollViewDidScroll:]` as I believe this will continue to be called as long as the scrollview is still scrolling, even if the user has stopped dragging.

Comment: I've used the [UIScrollViewDelegate scrollViewDidScroll:] method and it works fine.

Comment: I'll try the ease out curve. From my experience using scrollViewDidScroll, I end up with the mimic view being jumpy and not smooth.

Comment: I tried the animation, and unfortunately the duration is off by a bit and the curve still seems off. It seems like it needs to be updated every time `scrollViewDidScroll` is called, but I don't know how to get rid of the jumpiness.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible using just `decelerationRate` and a `CAMediaTimingFunction`. The reason is that UIScrollView (of which your UITableView is an instance) does not expose the timing function used for its deceleration. Also, for all we know, it is possible that the timing function used by UIScrollView cannot be fully calculated just from the `decelerationRate`. It might also be taking into account other factors, like the velocity, the length of space still available, or even factors invisible to you, etc..

Unless you can find someone who's reverse engineered all this stuff, I would suggest trying to find a way to let the original UIScrollView (that is, the UI TableView) drive the animation of your other view in addition its own content.

For instance, **could you simply make your other view a subview of one of the `UITableCell`s, or of the `UITableView` itself**, so that it inherited all its motion? If you don't clip to bounds, that might work just fine. You could even do this only for the duration of deceleration, if you did the view hierarchy manipulation before and after appropriate delegate methods.

Alternatively, you could implement the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll:`, grab the scroll view's contentOffset, and use that to compute the location of your other view, and just set its frame manually. This might work only for user-driven scrolling, rather than automatic deceleration. Also, you might need to get into the details of `NSRunLoop` modes to ensure that changes you apply during a scroll event take effect.

WWDC 2012, session "Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views", gives an example of capturing a UIScrollView's scroll movements and using it to drive the animation of OpenGL view.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest plugging into the scrollViewDidScroll: delegate call back and using the offset from that to reposition your other view.  You could even set a flag in scrollViewWillEndDragging: to start listening to scrollViewDidScroll:.  That's the only way I know of to match to movement exactly.

The trick with scrollViewDidScroll: is to not use an animation, but to set the frame or position directly.  The delegate is called back so frequently that an animation will look terrible.